# Cannot conect to server PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, failed-to-connect

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have been designing my schema in pgAdmin 4.7 and everything worked fine until I got this type of message for which I cannot find a solution. Any ideas?
[connection failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sby5E.jpg)

I tried to reboot but the problem persists

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The 4 is part of the name of the product, not a version number.  Is it pgAdmin4, 7.x?  In which case, what is the x?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The version is 4.7. I solved my problem by going to the services and stopping the service for postgresql-x64-15. Then by right-clicking, I chose properties, and on the "Log On" tab I chose "Local System account" and ticked "Allow service to interact with desktop". I don't know why but it solved my problem. Hopefully, someone knows the answer.